# What is IC marked `40D12BI`?

Tags: transistors, diodes, triac, igbt

What is the IC in the picture?

[image]

Comment: The manufacturer is [Nell Semi](https://www.nellsemi.com/eng/index.php). The only products they offer in a TO-3P package are Triacs and SCRs, but the markings match none of those. I suspect it's something custom that you won't find public information about.

Comment: Might be a Nell [40D12](https://www.nellsemi.com/eng/product_more_detail.php?id=239&cate=139) diode in custom package, but it's impossible to tell if that's plausible from your picture.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it right.